# Diseño de base de datos facturas pedidos

Tags: base-de-datos

Buenas , estoy diseñando una base de datos sencilla pero tengo algunas dudas en este sentido. intento hacer un sistema donde los doctores realicen una orden de trabajo y luego que esta sea generada se realice una factura. tengo dudas en como realizar las relaciones adjunto imágenes del diseño .... muchas gracias por su ayuda.
aqui adjunto una imagen de como lo tengo hasta ahora... es correcto esta relacion?

[image: posible distribución de la db]

Answer (score 1):

Solo un consejo de normalizado, estas generando redundancia de datos y aparte hay una propiedad que no recuerdo el nombre especifico que estas irrumpiendo para respetar el normalizado creo que datos derivados, pero:

El error esta en la relación de **CHECK**, no debería estar relacionada con **ORDERS**, o dependiendo de que informacion maneje, con **DOCTORS** porque?

> (No logra identificar si esa es la factura)

1) Digamos que el **CHECK** es el tipo de estado del doctor, 1 para trabajando 2 para en descanso.

Entonces el doctor de id: 15000 tendra estado_check en 1 y este correspondera a TRABAJANDO.

Cuando proceses **ORDERS** tendras.

id de la orden: 60, id del doctor 15000 id del check 1.

Cual es el prpoblema?, tu puedes obtener ese ID check desde el ID del doctor, algo como `SELECT estado_check FROM doctor WHERE id_doctor`

2) Digamos que **CHECK** es la factura, deberías relacionarla con la tabla **ORDERS** no con **DOCTOR**, porque?, porque de esta tabla **ORDERS** puedes sacar los demas datos, ya que en ella incluyes los ID de todos los datos.

3) Digamos que **CHECK** es un estado de la orden, 1 para cumplida, 2 para no cumplida, en este caso, **DOCTOR** no llevaria ninguna relacion con ella.

4) En fin para mi **CHECK** tomando dicha tabla como **FACTURA** quedaria con: `id, id_order, data, cantidad, price.` quitamos la relacion **DOCTOR - CHECK** y quedaria bien

De resto me parece que esta bien

Answer (score 0):

Para la generación de facturas siempre se debe crear una relación Maestro-Detalle en la que los datos generales de la factura estén en el Maestro(encabezado) y los productos o cosas que se añaden a tu factura estén en el detalle. En tu caso estás incluyendo todo en una sola tabla, ¿cada orden tiene distintos productos? si es así, entonces tienes que corregirlo y crear una relación Maestro-Detalle de la tabla **orders**